# Volume limited to the surface $|x|^{\frac{1}{3}}+|y|^{\frac{1}{3}}+|z|^{\frac{1}{3}}=|a|^{\frac{1}{3}}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How can I find the volume limited to the following surface?
$$|x|^{\frac{1}{3}}+|y|^{\frac{1}{3}}+|z|^{\frac{1}{3}}=|a|^{\frac{1}{3}}.$$
I used this iterated Integral
$$8\int_{0}^{|a|}\int_{0}^{(|a|^{\frac{1}{3}}-x^{\frac{1}{3}})^3}\int_{0}^{(|a|^{\frac{1}{3}}-x^{\frac{1}{3}}-y^{\frac{1}{3}})^3}dz\,dy\,dx$$
but its calculating is a bit difficult. Is there an easy way for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's overkill, but let's compute the $n$-volume $V(r)$ of
$$\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^\alpha=r^\alpha.$$
Certrainly $V(r)=r^n V(1)$. Let's consider the integral
$$I=\int\exp(-\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^\alpha)dx_1\dots dx_n.$$
On one hand
$$I=\int_0^\infty\exp(-r^\alpha)d(V(r))=V(1)\int_0^\infty e^{-s}\frac{n}{\alpha}s^{n/\alpha-1}ds=V(1)\Gamma(n/\alpha+1)$$
(here $s=r^\alpha$).
On the other hand 
$$I=(2\int_{0}^\infty e^{-|x|^\alpha}dx)^n=(2\Gamma(1/\alpha+1))^n$$
so 
$$V(r)=r^n(2\Gamma(1/\alpha+1))^n/\Gamma(n/\alpha+1).$$
In your case ($n=3,\alpha=1/3$) $V(r)=r^3 (2\times 3!)^3/9!=r^3/210$ (perhaps it's even true).

Comment: +1 cool, now I can upvote this. It is nice to have an approach to calculate all similar integrals at one shot.

Comment: Wonderful! Reminds me of many similar derivations in quantum field theory, where $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

Let us call the integral as $\mathscr{I}$.
By a change of variables $(x,y,z) = (au^3,av^3,aw^2)$, we can convert $\mathscr{I}$ to one over the simplex
$\displaystyle \Delta = \{\;(u,v,w) : 0 \le u, v, w; u + v + w \le 1\;\}$:

$$\mathscr{I} = 8 \int_{\Delta} d (a u^3)d(a v^3)d(a w^3)
= (6a)^3 \int_{\Delta} (uvw)^2 du dv dw$$

One way to deal with integrals over $\Delta$ is using coordinates $(\lambda,\mu,\nu)$ of the form:

$$\begin{cases}
\lambda & = u + v + w\\
\lambda \mu & = v + w\\
\lambda \mu \nu & = w
\end{cases}
\quad\iff\quad
\begin{cases}
u &= \lambda (1-\mu)\\
v &= \lambda \mu (1-\nu)\\
w &= \lambda \mu \nu
\end{cases}
$$
This will turn the integral over $\Delta$ to one over the unit cube $[0,1]^3$.
We have $$\begin{align}
du \wedge dv \wedge dw &= d(u + v + w) \wedge d(v+w) \wedge dw = d\lambda \wedge \lambda d\mu \wedge \lambda\mu d\nu = \lambda^2\mu d\lambda \wedge d\mu \wedge d\nu\\
u v w &= \lambda^3 \mu^2 (1-\mu) \nu (1-\nu)
\end{align}$$
This give us

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{I} &= (6a)^3 \left(\int_0^1 \lambda^8 d\lambda \right)\left( \int_0^1 \mu^5 (1-\mu)^2 d\mu \right)\left( \int_0^1 \nu^2(1-\nu)^2 d\nu \right)\\
&= (6a)^3 \left(\frac19\right)\left(\frac16 - \frac27 + \frac18 \right)\left(\frac13 - \frac24 + \frac15\right)\\
&= (6a)^3 \left(\frac19\right)\left(\frac{1}{168}\right)\left(\frac{1}{30}\right)\\
&= \frac{a^3}{210}
\end{align}$$
Alternatively, one can change coordinates to $(x,y,z) = (au^6,av^6,aw^6)$ and turn the integral over $\Delta$ to one over the one-eighth sphere $\Theta = \{\;(u,v,w) : 0 \le u, v, w; u^2 + v^2 + w^2 \le 1\;\}$.
We have
$$\mathscr{I} = 8 \int_{\Theta} d(a u^6) d(a v^6) d(a w^6) = (12a)^3 \int_{\Theta} (uvw)^5 du dv dw$$
Introduce spherical polar coordinates,

$$\begin{cases}
u &= r\sin\theta\cos\phi\\
v &= r\sin\theta\sin\phi\\
w &= r\cos\theta
\end{cases}
\quad\implies\quad
\begin{cases}
du dv dw &= r^2\sin\theta dr d\theta d\phi\\
uvw &= r^3 \sin^2\theta\cos\theta \sin\phi\cos\phi
\end{cases}$$

Our integral becomes
$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{I} & =
(12a)^3 \left(\int_0^1 r^{17} dr \right)
\left(\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^{11}\theta\cos^5\theta d\theta\right)
\left(\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^5\phi\cos^5\phi d\phi\right)\\
& = (12a)^3 \left(\frac{1}{18}\right) \left(\frac{1}{336}\right) \left(\frac{1}{60}\right)\\
&= \frac{a^3}{210}
\end{align}
$$